# how to add or remove tables dynamically in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to add a table row by clicking Add, and remove a table row by clicking the small red div inside the table, while retaining the color change option when table is clicked on.

I've been trying for hours, but i'm still new to ReactJS, maybe someone could give me a hint, how to do this, for example with help of an array, a boolean or a for loop? I can't get the right way yet, would be thankful for your input.

i've been thinking about this kind of logic, but haven't been able to implement it yet..

```
{Boolean(this.state.rows.length) && (
                <div onClick={this.handleRemoveRow}></div>
              )}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mattighof/0uop13kd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- Maintain a state say `list` and store all your items
- Create `onClick` handlers for adding and removing items in the table
- update the state when you add/remove
- iterate and render `this.state.list`
- Make sure to do `event.stopPropagation()` in the remove handler. this way your colour change functionality still works.

See here [the implementation of adding and removing item](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-remove-item-in-table-yge3g?file=/src/App.js)

**Code Snippet:**

```js
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableColor: true,
      list: []
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      tableColor: !this.state.tableColor
    });
  }
  addItem() {
    this.setState({ list: this.state.list.concat("item") });
  }
  removeItem(e, index) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ list: this.state.list.filter((_, i) => index !== i) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={this.addItem} type="button">
          Add
        </button>
        <table>
          {this.state.list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td
                  className={this.state.tableColor ? "trRed" : "trBlack"}
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                  {item}
                  <div
                    onClick={e => this.removeItem(e, index)}
                    className="innerDiv"
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: only, i noticed - when multiple TR's are created, clicking on one of them, changes color for all of them. Could this be cured with stopPropagation?

Comment: yes .. because.. you are maintaining a single colour for the whole table... so you need can modify the list array to array of object and maintain a colour and implement it ..

Comment: can you please help with this color change issue? i haven't been able to achieve the result even after a lot of trying.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways you can do it:

```
    class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
    rows:[{id:8,name:'item8',tablecColor:'trBlack'}],
      tableColor: true
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    this.renderRows = this.renderRows.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(clickedRow){
  const {rows} = this.state;
  let newRows = rows.map(row => {
  if(row.id === clickedRow.id) {
  row.tableColor = 'trRed'
  return row
  }
  return row;})
  this.setState({rows:newRows})
  }

  handleAdd() {
  const {rows} = this.state;
  const count = rows.length;
  rows.push({id:count,name:count,tablecColor:'trBlack'})
  this.setState({rows:rows})
  }

  renderRows() {
  return this.state.rows.map(row => {
  return (<tr>
            <td className={row.tableColor}>
              <div>{row.name} 
                <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(row)} 
                     className="innerDiv">
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
           </tr>)

  });
  }
  render(){
    return (
    <div className="container">
    <button type="button">Add</button>
    <table>
    {this.renderRows()}
    </table>
    </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```